# How to install pascal compiler in vim?

Tags: vim, compiler-construction, pascal

i have found pascal compiler for vim [there](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1376) but i dont know how to install it. There is no instruction. I dont know what i must do with it, and how compile a programs with it. 
Thank you.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with the concepts of setting these things up, you should probably start with an IDE like [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/)

Comment: Normally you don't install compilers "in" vim, there's no need. Also, that package is not the compiler itself, it's just a very small script file. To compile Pascal code itself, you'll need http://www.freepascal.org.

Comment: ok, i told a lie. I threw it in ftplugin folder, like i did with c, but when i typed something and then typed ":make" it wrote:":!make  2>&1| tee /var/folders/3v/bbg9bzzn47s9x0vjw7p1_fn80000gn/T/vxl4Va1/0
[No write since last change]
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
(1 of 1): make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop. ". And after that, i thought that the problem is in me, and i did something wrong.

Comment: Put it on `~/.vim/compiler/` and see `:help :compiler`.

Comment: Take a look at [SingleCompile plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3115) it will ease compiling and running of pascal files until you learn how to do it using `:make`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to have a look at the Vim documentation regarding the installation of plugins:
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html#plugin

**Excerpt**

```
USING A GLOBAL PLUGIN

First read the text in the plugin itself to check for any special conditions.
Then copy the file to your plugin directory:

    system      plugin directory 
    Unix        ~/.vim/plugin/
    PC and OS/2 $HOME/vimfiles/plugin or $VIM/vimfiles/plugin
    Amiga       s:vimfiles/plugin
    Macintosh   $VIM:vimfiles:plugin
    Mac OS X    ~/.vim/plugin/
    RISC-OS     Choices:vimfiles.plugin

Example for Unix (assuming you didn't have a plugin directory yet):

    mkdir ~/.vim
    mkdir ~/.vim/plugin
    cp /usr/local/share/vim/vim60/macros/justify.vim ~/.vim/plugin

That's all!  Now you can use the commands defined in this plugin to justify
text.

Instead of putting plugins directly into the plugin/ directory, you may
better organize them by putting them into subdirectories under plugin/.
As an example, consider using "~/.vim/plugin/perl/*.vim" for all your Perl
plugins.
```

Comment: Ok, a put it in the right directory. What's next? For example, i have a file demo.pas with code, and i opened it in vim. Also, a have fpc. How do i compile it?

Comment: freepascal.org has a lot of information about compiling FPC, and see also http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/buildfaq . Easiest is to simply download the .tar file, extract and run the script. Specially if you debian derived distros (packages always seem to be old in those)